# Alignment = Alignment.Middle in zebble

Tags: xamarin-zebble, zebble

I am developing a view in which I want to put the image in the middle of its container. it is ok to do so using this code:

```
<ImageView Path="Images/Menus/Basic/PhotoOptions/Photo camera.png" Alignment="Middle"></ImageView>
```

as you see I have done it by using Alignment="Middle" but it is always better to format every thing in CSS. so how can I make this happen in CSS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS has a property named background-position which is mapped to the Image Align feature in Zebble as they are semantically the same.

**Example markup:**

```
<ImageView Path="Images/Menus/Basic/PhotoOptions/Photo camera.png" 
           CssClass="some-class" />
```

**Css code:**

```
.some-class { background-position: center; }
```

Reference: http://zebble.net/docs/imageview